# Generating Hooks For Html test Runner Reports with Py-Installer exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing

How to generate hooks for Html test Runner Reports  with Py-Installer exe & how to use in below script?

```
import os
import sys
import time
import unittest

import HtmlTestRunner



class Test_J(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_Key1(self):
        
        pass

    def test_Key2(self):
        pass
 

    def test_Key3r(self):

        pass

  
if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        output1 = 'D:\\Reports'
        title1 = ' Testing Ver-1.0'
        name1 = ' Testing '

        unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output=output1, report_title=title1,
                                                               report_name=name1), exit=False,
                      verbosity=2)

  
        
    else:

        print("Thank You Tests Are Finished - Report Generated  )

      
        raw_input("Press Enter To Exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by writing external hook for html testrunner